# Definition of choice in Lean

Tags: lean

In [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/axioms_and_computation.html#choice), the axiom `choice` is implemented as follows:

> ```
> axiom choice {α : Sort u} : nonempty α → α
> ```
>
> Given only the assertion `h` that `α` is nonempty, `choice h` magically produces an element of `α`.

Now if I read literature (Jech) on set theory and the axiom of choice:

> Axiom of Choice (AC). Every family of nonempty sets has a choice function.
>
> If `S` is a family of sets and `∅` not in `S`, then a choice function for `S` is a function `f` on `S` such that `f(X) ∈ X` for every `X ∈ S`.

To me, these things don't seem to be equivalent. Can someone elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axiom `choice` in Lean is indeed not the same as the axiom of choice in set theory. The axiom `choice` in Lean doesn't really have a corresponding statement in set theory. It says that there is a *function* that takes a proof that some type `α` is nonempty, and produces an inhabitant of `α`. In set theory, we cannot define functions that take proofs as arguments since proofs are not objects in set theory; they are in the layer of logic on top of that.

That said, the two choice axioms are not completely unrelated. From Lean's axiom `choice`, you can prove the more familiar axiom of choice from set theory, which you can find [here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Classical.html#Classical.axiomOfChoice):

```
theorem axiomOfChoice {α : Sort u} {β : α → Sort v} {r : ∀ x, β x → Prop}
        (h : ∀ x, ∃ y, r x y) : ∃ (f : ∀ x, β x), ∀ x, r x (f x) :=
  ⟨_, fun x => choose_spec (h x)⟩
```

In other parts of the library, other equivalent statements to the axiom of choice are proven, like the one stating that [every surjective function has a right inverse](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/Logic/Function/Basic.html#Function.rightInverse_surjInv).

Maybe the statement closest to the version of the axiom of choice you quoted is the following:

```
theorem axiomOfChoice' {α : Sort u} {β : α → Sort v} (h : ∀ x, Nonempty (β x)) :
        Nonempty (∀ x, β x) :=
  ⟨fun x => Classical.choice (h x)⟩
```

In words, this says that given a family of nonempty types (sets), the type of choice functions is nonempty. As you can see the proof is immediate from Lean's `choice`.